# SVN Setup Of Existing Directory

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I have been going through documentation and such and have SVN working, but I want to put it on an existing directory.  I imported that directory, so do I rename/delete the non SVN directory and then checkout the SVN to the non SVN directory location?  I am just trying to understand how to get it to start posting to our website URL.

If so, is there any way to keep the current non SVN and make it SVN rather than import and overwrite?

Thanks, I am trying to understand SVN, but find a lot of the tutorials and such on the web to be confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have it exactly.  Once your code has been added to the repository, you can get rid of or rename your original code directory.  Then checkout the project from the repository into the same location as your previous code and continue working from there.

**UPDATE**

To make it so that your website is updated from the repository, you actually need *two* working directories, and a repository.

**Repository:** The repository stores the code and changesets, but isn't directly accessible as a file system.  Keep a backup!.

**Working directory 1:** You develop and test your code from a working directory checked out from the repository.  Commit changes back to the repository.

**Working directory 2:** Rename the code directory on your webserver. Checkout a copy of the code to your web server in its place.  Technically it is now a working directory, since it contains the `.svn` metadata directories, though you won't usually make changes here.

Make changes to your code from your development working directory (1) and commit them back to the repository.  When you are satisfied that they are working correctly and have been properly tested, on the web server's code copy (2) do `svn update` (or if you're using Tortoise SVN on the web server, do an update).  This will synchronize the server code with the current development version.

Subversion will not automatically push updates to your web server.  You will need to pull them in with an update when you need to.  It is possible to use what's called a "post-commit hook" to cause Subversion to execute a script when commits are made, and that script could update or export code to your production web server.  However, you would need to write the script and it's kind of an advanced usage of Subversion. I would recommend trying out the method I described with a working copy on the web server to get accustomed to the workflow befrore trying anything more complicated.

**Addendum** If you really want to do this (and I don't really recommend it unless you really test well) a very easy method would be to schedule a cron job that does `svn update` every couple of hours (or minutes) on your production site.

Don't forget that if you do happen to modify your code directly on the web server, you must commit it back to the repository from there, and do an update on your development working copy.

Comment: I did this, but commits still don't go to the working directory.  Am I missing something.

Comment: @fanfavorite in the working directory, you should see output for `svn info`

Comment: @fanfavorite Commits (`svn commit`) are made back to the repository from the working directory.  If a commit is made elsewhere, you must run `svn update` in the working directory to bring it up to the latest code version

Comment: I am so confused.  All I want is when I use tortoiseSVN, for those commits to be reflected on the website.  The way I have it is the website directory is the working directory, perhaps I have the other part wrong.  Locally, I connect to svn to the svn directory and not the working directory.  Should I be connecting to the working directory instead?

Comment: From what I am thinking I understand, my local download is a working directory and the live server is a working directory and what is posted to it is the repository.  So I would have to svn update the live server all the time.  If this is the case, is there a way to sync it automatically or should I setup the respository as the test server?  Without svn, we have /var/www/html/live and /var/www/html/test.  Just trying to get the best solution here.  We will want to apply some changes to test at certain times.  Thanks.

Comment: You have the setup right, but are missing some steps.  See my update above.  Basically it boils down to needing to update on the website working directory when you have committed changes from your local development working directory

Comment: @fanfavorite your last comment came while I was typing out the summary above.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  You have helped me understand things better now.